# Angular 1.x service injection in unit tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I've been trying different variations based on the info that's out there, but haven't got to a working solution yet.

I'm trying to inject a service into a unit test for testing.

My current implementation is below. The issue is, the service isn't: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: SerializationService` - I've tried using `inject()` in the beforeeach too to no avail.

spec.js

```
'use strict';

describe('SerializationService', function () {

  var SerializationService;

  beforeEach(function () {

    module('app');

    inject(function (_SerializationService_) {
      SerializationService = _SerializationService_;
    });
  });

  it('should have a SerializationService', function () {
    expect(SerializationService).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Other things I've tried:

- Using separate module includes between the app module and injecting services in another foreach using the underscore notation

karma.conf

```
// Karma configuration
// http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html
// Generated on 2016-08-15 using
// generator-karma 0.8.3

module.exports = function (config) {
  'use strict';

  config.set({
    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '../../',

    // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
      'bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js',
      'bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js',
      'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js',
      'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      'bower_components/angular-audio/app/angular.audio.js',
      'bower_components/socket.io.client/dist/socket.io-1.3.5.js',
      'bower_components/angular-socket-io/socket.js',
      'bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.js',
      'bower_components/moment/moment.js',
      'bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js',
      'bower_components/angular-scroll-glue/src/scrollglue.js',
      'bower_components/angular-gravatar/build/angular-gravatar.js',
      'bower_components/angular-socialshare/dist/angular-socialshare.min.js',
      'bower_components/clipboard/dist/clipboard.js',
      'bower_components/ngclipboard/dist/ngclipboard.js',
      'bower_components/color-thief/src/color-thief.js',
      'bower_components/ngColorThief/angular-colorthief.js',
      'bower_components/hashids/dist/hashids.js',
      'bower_components/ngEmbed/src/ng-embed.js',
      'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
      'bower_components/ngEmbed/src/ng-embed.js',
      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      'test/unit/mock/**/*.js',
      'test/unit/spec/**/*.js'
    ],

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [],

    // web server port
    port: 8081,

    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera
    // - Safari (only Mac)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows)
    browsers: [
      'PhantomJS'
    ],

    // Which plugins to enable
    plugins: [
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine'
    ],

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false,

    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO

    //// Uncomment the following lines if you are using grunt's server to run the tests
    // proxies: {
    //   '/': 'http://localhost:9000/'
    // },
    // //URL root prevent conflicts with the site root
    // urlRoot: '_karma_'
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was in my mocking modules

I was using the crate method instead of the get:

This is wrong:

```
angular
  .module('meow-mock', [])
  .factory('somemock', function () {
  //code
  });
```

This is right:

```
angular
  .module('meow-mock')
  .factory('somemock', function () {
  //code
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a little sample on plunker: [Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/5qplw2)

It uses angular-mocks and jasmine for testing.
The main part:

```
describe('TestService', function(){
  beforeEach(module('test'));

  var TestService;
  beforeEach(inject(function(_TestService_) {
    TestService = _TestService_;
  }));

  it('returns 42', function(){
    expect(TestService.testMethod()).toEqual(42);
  });
});
```

You have to use `inject`, which is defined in angular-mocks. It injects services, controllers, etc. The underscores are automatically stripped, it is only syntactic sugar to be able to name your variable as `TestService`

Comment: Hey dude, thanks for your answer - I've tried implementing this but am receiving `    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: SerializationServiceProvider <- SerializationService` still seems to be an issue. I'm wondering if it's to do with the `karma.conf` too? For reference I pasted it into the original question as well. Thank you :)

Comment: Could you update your post to include your test code? (i.e. the file with the `describe`)

Comment: Looks OK to me, it's probably something with the karma config then.
Are you sure that `basePath: '../../'` is correct? karma.conf is in a sub-sub directory under the root dir?
If karma.conf is in the root of your project, you should use `basePath: '.'`

Comment: Yep base path is correct, it's nested in `test/unit/` :/